# Multiple audio tags not working well together

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am attempting to write a soundboard website for a project of mine and I want the ability to click on an `<a>` tag and have it play the audio to a certain `<audio>` tag. As of now, I am using this code which I found on SO:

```
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio src="1.aif"></audio>1</a>
```

While this works in most cases, while using it on iOS, if you click on the "1" instead of the a, it will select a different element to play (I have multiple on the page). My thinking was that I should have it so that when you click on the `<a>`, it plays a certain `<audio>` clip via a class,

```
<a onclick="(.1).play()"><audio class="1" src="1.aif"></audio>1</a>
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it though, and if it is, what the syntax to call the class instead of `firstChild` would be. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're giving individual class names to elements really that's what id is for. (Class is more appropriate to apply to multiple elements.) So maybe something like:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('a1').play()"><audio id="a1" src="1.aif"></audio>1</a>
```

Having said that, the way to get elements by class is using [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) - note that it returns elements, plural, as a NodeList, so even if you know there is only one element with a given class you have to allow for that:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('1')[0].play()"><audio class="1" src="1.aif"></audio>1</a>
```

Note that as shown in the [Quirksmode compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11) not all browsers support `.getElementsByClassName()`.

(You could also use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), but it isn't supported by older browsers either.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This also does solve the problem... I'm not sure why, but if I had multiple `<a>` elements floated, it would select the wrong one if you clicked on the text instead of the `<a>`. Anyways, thanks for the help